# Reverse of Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem

Tags: calculus

[Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) says, 
if $$f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y),$$
then one has: $$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=nf(x,y)$$

However, can we reverse it? ie.
if $$f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y),$$
and there exist 2 functions $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ such that $$xg(x,y)+yh(x,y)=nf(x,y).$$
then can we say that it must be $$g(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ and  $$h(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,?$$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro updated again.

Comment: Not exactly your question, but there is a different way of "reversing" Euler's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity

Comment: now i get the whole picture, thanks! @TheoreticalEconomist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $f(x, y)=x^2+y^2$, which is $2$-homogeneous. It satisfies 
$$
2f(x, y)= xg(x, y)+yh(x, y)$$ 
with $g(x, y)= 2x+ 2y, h(x, y)=2y-2x$, so $g\ne \partial_x f$ and $h\ne\partial_y f$.

Comment: How about in general $n$? Eg if $n=1$, does it hold ?

Comment: No. With $f=(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}$ and $g=\partial_x f +ny, h=\partial_y f-nx$ you get a counterexample for all $n$.

Comment: Ok but I am wondering whether we can say that there exists atleast one solution of f which satisfies that partial differential equation and is also homogeneous?